# How to access a variable across sessions in PHP?

Tags: variables, global, php

This may sound a bit catchy, but i want to access variable across sessions.
I want to store a variable in a session and want to access it even after i navigate away from my website and come back some time later.

Thanks in advance :)
Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

You need a cookie for that. http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp

Comment: but i dont want to use a cookie here as i'm storing some sensitive info in there :) and not even DB as i want to make this implementation easy without DB .. can u see of any other indirect alternatives :) Thanks for ur reply..

Comment: You could encrypt the data before putting it in the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with sessions in [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) you can get a little explain about that

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built in mechanism for using sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

here is a super simple example from their tutorial:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS with PHP 4.0.6 or less
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with php is to use cookies because the only data stored in browser's storage are cookies.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expires in 1 hour */
```

After you set the cookie you can get it's value until expiration time with referencing `$_COOKIE` automatic global variable.

```
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```